# Wrongly place on sex regristry

Tags: defamation, slander

I found one my friends listed on the sex registry. He is incarcerated. He was shocked. He has never been tried, convicted or served time for a sex crime. Alot of paperwork and finding info he is now off. However he was on it for 22 yrs. Can he sue? I'm am 200% sure its defamation and slander. I'm just thankful he'd off the registry but what about  the time, he lost seeing his grandkids growing up plus his own kids.  Ty

Comment: If he didn't even know he was on the list how could it have kept him from seeing his grandkids?

Comment: To be honest, his children might have just told him they don't want him anywhere near the grand children (because they found he was on a registry), without telling him the reason.

Answer (score 1):

If defamatory misinformation were put on a sex offender registry, there is little chance that the defamed person can sue for damages. These registries are government operations, and the doctrine of sovereign immunity prevents the government from being sued, unless they explicitly give permission to be sued over some wrong. There are 50 states and the federal government to consider so it matters where the error is, but governments generally immunize themselves against liability for errors in these lists. E.g. [Texas law](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/CR/htm/CR.62.htm) (Art. 62.008-.009) immunizes various individuals and institutions in connection with the sex offender registry.

Because there is no legal notification requirement whereby a person convicted of a "sex offense" must be notified that he is now a statutorily-defined sex offender, a person especially one still incarcerated may be unaware of his status. Public urination is an example of a surprise sex offense. Your friend's being surprised doesn't mean that the information (formerly?) on the registry was false.